# May i Use ShortCode in Template?

Tags: plugins, functions, shortcode

Am Using Wordpress Blog.Here i want Use Tweetmeme Plugin.I want to show the output of the Tweetmeme Plugin to Customizing place(Side of the Post[Not Before or After]).The Plugin Creators are providing Shortcode.Shall i Use this shortcode in Template?I Guess this is not possible.So we need to change Shortcode as a function.How to Create a function from Shortcode?please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using the `do_shortcode()` function?

**EDIT**

I'm not familiar with the TweetMeme shortcode, but here's an example usage for putting a NextGen Gallery directly into a template file:

```
echo do_shortcode( '[slideshow id="1" w="603" h="270"]' );
```

Simply replace with the appropriate shortcode (and parameters) for TweetMeme.

Codex ref: [do_shortcode()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode)

**EDIT 2**

With TweetMeme, you have another option:

1. Change the Plugin "where" setting from "shortcode" to "manual"
2. Place the `tweetmeme()` function in your Theme template file where you want to output the TweetMeme button.

Comment: your Answer was Excellent. But it's not working for Tweetmeme plugin. I added this coding... `<?php do_shortcode('[tweetmeme]');?> <?php echo do_shortcode('[tweetmeme]'); ?>`  Anything Wrong here?

Comment: Why are you calling `do_shortcode()` twice? Also, see my edited answer for another option.

Comment: Thx yaar,It's Working fine...